# Frobenius map and pth roots of elements of the ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring (with unit) of characteristic $p>0.$

Suppose $R$ is domain and $L$ is some algebraic closure of the quotient field of $R.$ Then we can define $R^{1/p}=\{a\in L: a^p\in R\}$, i.e. $R^{1/p}$
 is the set of all $p$th roots of elements of $R.$

**What is the meaning of $R^{1/p}$ (the set of all $p$ th roots of elements of $R$) when $R$ is reduced?**

**If $R$ is reduced then how to show that the Frobenius map $F:R\longrightarrow R$ ($F(r)=r^p$) is isomorphic to the inclusion map $R\subset R^{1/p}.$**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inclusion $R \subset R^{1/p}$ is just another name for the inclusion $R^p \subset R$. There is no harm to this as the Frobenius yields an isomorphism $R \cong R^p$ if $R$ is reduced. When working with $R^{1/p}$, this is all you have to know. But it makes sense to formalize this once and forever.

Before we formalize this, let us learn from the case, where $R$ is a domain and where $R^{1/p}$ is already defined. Note that we have an isomorphism $R^{1/p} \to R, r \mapsto r^p$ and the composition $R \subset R^{1/p} \to R$ is just the Frobenius map $F: R \to R$. Hence we have factored Frobenius into an inclusion, followed by an isomorphism.

**That is all we need to imitiate.** Assume we have found

1. a ring $S$,
2. an inclusion $R \xrightarrow{i} S$,
3. an isomorphism $j:S \to R$,

such that $R \xrightarrow{i} S \xrightarrow{j} R$ is the Frobenius map. Then $S$ has exactly the properties we wish for $R^{1/p}$:

1) The $p$-th power of an element in $S$ is contained in $R$ via $i$: $$s^p=j^{-1}(j(s^p))=j^{-1}(j(s)^p) = j^{-1}(F(j(s)))=i(j(s)).$$

2) Every element of $R$ has $p$-th root in $S$:
$$i(r)=i(j(j^{-1}(r)))=(j^{-1}(r))^p.$$

---

Let us find such an $S$. For convenience, let us denote the co-domain of the Frobenius map by $T$, i.e. the Frobenius map is $F: R \to T$ (and actually $T=R$).

Let us define $S = R \otimes_R T$, where $T$ is an $R$-module via $F$ (In the literature $T$ is denoted by $F_*R$). As any tensor product of two rings, this becomes a ring.

We have an inclusion *(In general, the kernel is precisely the kernel of $R \to T$, so this is where the reduced property is needed)* $$i: R \hookrightarrow R \otimes_R T, r \mapsto r \otimes 1$$ and the $R$-module isomorphism $$j: R \otimes_R T \to T, r \otimes t \mapsto r \cdot t =r^pt$$ is of course a ring map by the very definition of the ring structre of the tensor product (This holds for a general ring map $R \to T$).

Clearly the composition $R \to R \otimes_R T \to T$ sends $r$ to $r^p$, hence is the Frobenius map. Thus $S$ is as desired.

**Conclusion:** One can define $R^{1/p} := R \otimes_R F_*R$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It is really helpful to me. In 2), i think i(r)=j^{-1}(j(i(r))) (since F=ji).

Answer (score 2):

> $\def\frq{\mathfrak{q}}$*Exercise 1.* If $S$ is a reduced ring of characteristic $p$ and $s\in S$, then $x^p-s\in S[x]$ either has no roots or has a unique root of multiplicity $p$.

Thus, if $x^p-s$ has a root in $S$, the symbol $\sqrt[p]{s}$ denotes a unique element of $S$.

In the following, $R$ is a reduced ring of prime characteristic $p$.

We will define $R^{1/p}$ via a universal property. Before, let us introduce some definitions: We say that an $R$-algebra $S$ is *closed under $p$-th $R$-roots* if for each $r\in R$ there is $s\in S$ such that $s^p=g(r)$, where $g:R\to S$ is the structure morphism, i.e., $S$ has all $p$-th roots of $g(R)$. Consider the full subcategory $\mathsf{C}\subset R\text{-}\mathsf{Alg}$ of the reduced $R$-algebras that are closed under $p$-th $R$-roots. We define $R^{1/p}$ to be an initial object in $\mathsf{C}$.

We just need to show $R^{1/p}$ exists. We claim it is the Frobenius homomorphism $F:R\to R$. Let $g:R\to S$ be an object in $\mathsf{C}$. We want to factor $g$ through $F$. Define $\overline{g}:R\to S$ to be the map that sends $r\in R$ to $\sqrt[p]{g(r)}\in S$. By uniqueness of $p$-th roots and the fact that $(-)^p:S\to S$ is a ring homo, it is easy to verify that $\overline{g}$ is a ring homomorphism. By construction, $\overline{g}\circ F=g$. We now see uniqueness of $\overline{g}$: if $\tilde{g}$ were another such factorization, then $\overline{g}(r)^p=\overline{g}(r^p)=g(r)=\tilde{g}(r^p)=\tilde{g}(r)^p$. Since $S$ is reduced, $(-)^p:S\to S$ is injective, so $\overline{g}(r)=\tilde{g}(r)$.

> **Lemma 2.** An object $g:R\to S\in\mathsf{C}$ is initial in $\mathsf{C}$ if and only if $g(R)=S^p$.

*Proof.* On the one hand, if $g$ is initial in $\mathsf{C}$, then $g\cong F$ so the claim is trivial. The proof of the converse is left as an exercise, since it is very similar to the proof that $F$ is initial. $\square$

> *Exercise 3.* If $S$ is a reduced ring of characteristic $p$ and $s\in S$ is such that $x^p-s\in S[x]$ has no roots in $S$, then $S[x]/(x^p-s)$ is reduced (i.e., $(x^p-s)\subset S[x]$ is a radical ideal).

With the universal-property definition, we can write the Frobenius map $F:R\to R$ in a quite suggestive way.

> **Lemma 4.** $F$ is isomorphic to the unique $R$-algebra map
> $$
> f:R\to
> \frac{R[x_r\mid r\in R,\sqrt[p]{r}\not\in R]}
> {(x_r^p-r\mid r\in R,\sqrt[p]{r}\not\in R)}=R'
> $$

By “$\sqrt[p]{r}\not\in R$” we mean “there is no $p$-th root of $r$ in $R$.” The fact $F\cong f$ makes precise the idea that “$R^{1/p}$ is obtained by formally adding to $R$ a $p$-th root of each element that hadn't one.”

*Proof.* We need to verify two things: that $f$ is an object in $\mathsf{C}$ and that it is initial in $\mathsf{C}$. Suppose we knew $R'$ is reduced. Then it is easy to show that $f$ is an object of $\mathsf{C}$ which is initial (Lemma 2). Thus, we just need to verify $R'$ is reduced. While undertaking the  search for a proof of the reducedness of $R'$, one might encounter the following difficulty: if $r,s\in R$ are distinct elements of $R$ with no $p$-th root in $R$, then the ideal $(x^p-r,y^p-s)$ might no be radical in $R[x,y]$. Intuitively, this is because adjoining one single $p$-th root to $R$ might automatically add other $p$-th roots: Given an element $r\in R$, it is easy to show by induction that $\sqrt[p]{r}\in R$ if and only if $\sqrt[p]{r+n}\in R$, for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. We can overcome this difficulty in the following way: we will use the result *a filtered colimit of reduced rings is reduced* (it follows from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2737301/reducedness-and-colimit#comment5649960_2737614)). Let's write then $R'$ as a filtered colimit of reduced rings: For each $T\subset R$, write
$$
R_T=\frac{R[x_r\mid r\in T]}{(x_r^p-r\mid r\in T)}.
$$
Define a category $\mathsf{I}$, whose objects are finite subsets $T\subset R$ such that $R_T$ is reduced (thus $\sqrt[p]{r}\not\in R$ for all $r\in T$; note the converse might not hold, because of the phenomenon pointed out before). Given objects $T_1,T_2\in \mathsf{I}$, we observe that there is at most one morphism of $R$-algebras $R_{T_1}\to R_{T_2}$ (use Exercise 1). In such a case, we will say there is a unique morphism $T_1\to T_2$ in $\mathsf{I}$ (so $\mathsf{I}$ is a thin small category).

Define a diagram
\begin{align*}
D:\mathsf{I}&\to\mathsf{Ring}\\
T&\mapsto R_T
\end{align*}
where the action on morphisms sends $T_1\to T_2$ to the unique $R$-algebra map $R_{T_1}\to R_{T_2}$.

We first verify that $R'$ is the colimit of this diagram. It is clear that $R'$ is a cocone under $D$. It is a limiting cocone since given a cocone $\mathcal{A}=\{R_T\to A\}_{T\in\mathsf{I}}$ under $D$, in particular we have maps $\varphi:R=R_\varnothing\to A$ and $\psi_r:R_{\{r\}}\to A$, for each $r\in R$ such that $\sqrt[p]{r}\not\in R$ ($\{r\}$ is in $\mathsf{I}$ by Exercise 3). Thus, there is a canonical map $R'\to A$ that acts as $\varphi$ on coefficients and that sends the coset of $x_r$ in $R'$ to $\psi_r(x_r)\in A$. It is not difficult to see that $R'\to A$ factors $\mathcal{A}$. Uniqueness of the factorization $R'\to A$ comes from the fact that a ring morphism $R'\to B$ is fully determined by the composites with $R=R_\varnothing\to R'$ and with $R_{\{r\}}\to R'$, where $r\in R$ is such that $\sqrt[p]{r}\not\in R$ (i.e., $R'\to B$ is determined by the action on coefficients in $R$ and the action on the cosets of the $x_r$'s).

It is left to see that $\mathsf{I}$ is a filtered category. On the one hand, it is non-empty, for $\varnothing\in\mathsf{I}$. Since $\mathsf{I}$ is thin, we just need to show that given $T_1,T_2\in\mathsf{I}$, there is $T\in\mathsf{I}$ such that there are morphisms $T_1\to T\leftarrow T_2$ in $\mathsf{I}$. Note that there is an $R$-algebra morphism $T_1\to T_2$ in $\mathsf{I}$ if and only if all $r\in T_1$ have a $p$-th root in $R_{T_2}$. If there is an $R$-algebra morphism $T_1\to T_2$, we are done. Otherwise, pick some $r\in T_1$ without a $p$-th root in $R_{T_2}$. Then $R_{T_2\cup\{r\}}=R_{T_2}[x]/(x^p-r)$ is reduced (Exercise 3), i.e., $T_2\cup\{r\}\in\mathsf{I}$. We may replace $T_2$ by $T_2\cup\{r\}$ (for there is a morphism $T_2\to T_2\cup\{r\}$ in $\mathsf{I}$). Now $r$ has a $p$-th root in $R_{T_2}$. If at this moment there is $T_1\to T_2$, we are done; otherwise, we repeat the same process. Since $T_1$ is finite this process finds a morphism $T_1\to T_2$ in a finite number of steps, and we win. $\square$

There are two special cases in which $R^{1/p}$ has other presentations:

1. If $R$ is an integral domain, then we can consider its field of fractions $Q(R)$ and embed $R$ in an algebraic closure $R\subset\overline{Q(R)}$. Define $S=\{s\in\overline{Q(R)}\mid s^p\in R\}$. Then it is easy to verify that $S$ is a subring of $\overline{Q(R)}$. We have that $S$ is an $R$-algebra closed under $p$-th $R$-roots, and it is initial in $\mathsf{C}$ thanks to Lemma 2.
2. In the case when $R$ has finitely many minimal primes $\frq_1,\dots,\frq_t$ (this happens for instance if $R$ is Noetherian), we can give yet another construction for $R^{1/p}$. In this case, by [00EW](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00EW)(3) we are under the hypotheses of [02LX](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02LX). Thus the total ring of fractions of $R$ is $Q(R)=R_{\frq_1}\times\cdots \times R_{\frq_t}$. By [00EU](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00EU), each factor $R_{\frq_i}$ is a field. Taking algebraic closure in each factor, we have an inclusion $R\subset K:=\overline{R_{\frq_1}}\times\cdots \times \overline{R_{\frq_t}}$. Define $S=\{s\in K\mid s^p\in R\}$. Then it is easy to verify that $S$ is a subring of $K$. On the other hand, $S$ is reduced (for $K$, being a product of reduced rings, is reduced), and $R\subset S$, so that $S$ is an $R$-algebra closed under $p$-th roots. By Lemma 2, it is initial in $\mathsf{C}$, i.e., $S=R^{1/p}$.